# Mysql count distinct with condition or case

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT user_appoint.TreatmentCaseId,
user_appoint.TreatmentCase,
tbl_rank.rank, 
user_appoint.u_id, 
DATE_FORMAT(MAX(user_appoint.ApptDateTime), ("%d-%m-%Y")) AS mdate, 
(CASE user_appoint.TreatmentCase 
WHEN 1 THEN "Open" WHEN 0 THEN "Closed" 
WHEN 2 THEN "Hospitalized" ELSE "" END) AS CaseStatus,
user_det.dob FROM (`user_appoint`) JOIN `user_det` ON 
`user_appoint`.`u_id` = `user_det`.`id` JOIN `tbl_rank` ON 
`user_appoint`.`rank` = `tbl_rank`.`rank_id` WHERE 
`user_appoint`.`comp_id` = '123' AND 
`user_appoint`.`void` = 0 AND 
`user_appoint`.`purpose` = 2 AND 
`TreatmentCaseId` LIKE '%%' 
GROUP BY 
`user_appoint`.`TreatmentCaseId` 
LIMIT 5
```

This is my query and i am getting the result as

```
   TreatmentCaseId   TreatmentCase  mdate       CaseStatus    dob         

   A11                   2          10-03-2015  Hospitalized  1988-08-20  
   A12                   0          27-11-2014  Closed        1986-08-26  
   A13                   1          26-11-2014  Open          1988-08-20  
   A14                   1          25-11-2014  Open          1988-08-20
```

and now i want to count the number of casestatus i.e 
i will get
open=2 , closed=1 , hospitalized=1
The date that is been select is the max date, so based on the max date i have selected the column and after that column is selected the number of open , closed and hospitalized cases will be counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional `sum`:

```
select sum(CaseStatus = 'Open') as OpenedCount
     , sum(CaseStatus = 'Closed') as ClosedCount
     , sum(CaseStatus = 'Hospitalized') as HospitalizedCount
from (<...>)
```

Comment: not getting the result bro ! The openedCount is showing empty

Comment: @RajParekh: Typo, got confused, you are mixing present/past tenses. (Changed `Opened` to `Open`)

Answer (score 1):

select count(*), CaseStatus
from ("your previous query")
group by CaseStatus;